# Migrating changes from one sql database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Several databases: 
DB_Dev
DB_Test
DB_Prod

When new columns are needed or existing columns need to be altered, they are always changed on DB_Dev first and then the changes copied to the others when everyone is happy.

Is there any tools that will look at two databases, show the changes, and allow to make those same changes to the second database automatically? Changes will only be forward - ie, DB_Dev will never be out of date.

Comment: A useful technique is to make all changes to `DB_Dev` using scripts, then you can apply the same scripts to `DB_Test` and then, if they pass, to `DB_Prod`.

Comment: I would not recommend applying these changes automatically, especially too your production database. I would recommend creating a database project with visual studio and use the deployment features.

Comment: Another option is the latest SQL Server Data Tools which will do schema comparison and output change scripts or apply them automatically.  Redgate also have some neat tools to do this.